# ofStream printing in another function

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a weird problem going on. I have two functions, which both have an ofstream passed by reference. However when I call the second function, part of the first function is being printed.

Here is the first function:

```
void GamePlay::dealDominos(ofstream& outStream, int seed){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {

       outStream << "random " << rand() << endl; 

    }
}
```

My second function is:

```
void GamePlay::findLongestSeq(ofstream& outStream)
{
    outStream << toStringSeq(label, maxSeq) << endl;
}
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
NEW MAX [  T   0  8 ]
NEW MAX random [  T   0  8 ][  T   8  1 ]
NEW MAX ndom [  T   0  8 ][  T   8  1 ][  T   1  1 ][  T   1  2 ]
NEW MAX dom [  T   0  8 ][  T   8  1 ][  T   1  1 ][  T   1  2 ][  T   2 11 ]
MAX SEQ FOR:    dom [  T   0  8 ][  T   8  1 ][  T   1  1 ][  T   1  2 ][  T   2 11 ]
```

I don't want the word "random" to be printed between the label and the sequence..

How do I fix this?

Comment: How are these functions being called? From different threads?

Comment: They are being called from a main class.

    'GamePlay game;
    game.dealDominos(outStream, seed);
    game.findLongestSeq(outStream);'

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to do the code syntax in a comment.

Comment: (to do that, surround the code with backticks). Superficially, it looks like two threads are writing to the stream at the same time and the results are interleaving. Except your comment suggests otherwise, and some parts of the word "random" are missing altogether, as are the actual random numbers. So I don't know. What does `toStringSeq()` look like?

Comment: either `toStringSeq` has a problem, or the code which calls both of these functions. You need to show the code that has the problem

Comment: `string GamePlay::toStringSeq(string label, const vector<Domino>& theSeq) const`
{
    
   ` #ifdef EBUG`
   ` Utils::logStream << "enter toStringSeq\n";`
    `#endif`
    `string s = "";`
    
    `s+= label + " ";`
    `s+= theSeq.size() + " ";`
    
    `for (int  i = 0; i < theSeq.size(); i++)`
  `  {`
        `s+= theSeq[i].toString();`
        
   ` }`
   
    `#ifdef EBUG`
   ` Utils::logStream << "leave toStringSeq\n";`
   ` #endif`
   ` return s;`
`}`

Comment: Have you got two separate `ofstream` objects referring to the same underlying file?

Comment: Well I passed it by reference so there is only one object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got two separate `ofstream` objects referring to the same underlying file, which is a pretty bad idea unless you're going to do lots of seek operations and flushes on every write, to ensure the file positions get updated for every write.

Comment: I only have one object and pass it by reference.

Comment: If the ofstream is actually cout or cerr and you use one of these, too, then it would look exactly like this. So check if you use cout or cerr.

Comment: @dom0, could you explain some more about that?